# PHP equivalent to the JavaScript parentNode Property

Tags: javascript, php, dom, parent

I'd like to check the id of the parent element, to display either the big or the small version of an image.

```
<div id="content">
  <?php include 'test.php';?>
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
  <?php include 'test.php';?>
</div>
```

In test.php, an if-statement checks if the parent has the demanded id.
Is there a way to get the parentnode-id without JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. PHP do nothing with the rendered page. 
But why don't you create a function and call that with parameters?

```
include 'test.php'
?>
<div id="content">
  <?php showImage(); ?>
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
  <?php showImage(true); ?>
</div>

<?php
```

And in test.php

```
function showImage($smallImage = false) {
    if (!$smallImage) {
        echo '<img src="path/to/bigimage" alt="" />';
    } else {
        echo '<img src="path/to/smallimage" alt="" />';
    }

}
```

Or **there are an alternative way**. Set a variable before you include your file, and you can set an if condition in your test.php when you want to show the image.

```
<div id="content">
    <?php
    $parentNode = 'content';
    include 'test.php'
    ?>
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
    <?php
    $parentNode = 'sidebar';
    include 'test.php'
    ?>
</div>
```